# How to filter dataframe and get the total number of records based on another column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly-dash

I have collected jira data and written it into a csv file where the dataframe which I have gathered has `Ticket_No`, `Request Type`, `Assignee Name` and `Status` as the columns. What I want to achieve is count the number of `In Progress`, `Open` and `Closed` tickets in order to visualize it in a plotly bar graph with `Assignees` on the x-axis and `Status` on the y-axis. Is it possible? Below is the sample dataset. The plotly is not plotting anything for the x and y axis that I have given (obviously).

- Note: Whereever there is a 'New' in the status there is blank in the Assignee Name

```py
N;Issue key;Request Type;Assignee name;Status
0;JIRA_1;Bug;User1;Awaiting Review
1;JIRA_2;Improvement;User2;In Progress
2;JIRA_3;Improvement;;New
3;JIRA_4;Improvement;User3;Closed
4;JIRA_5;Improvement;User3;Awaiting Review
5;JIRA_6;Improvement;;New
6;JIRA_7;Bug;User5;Closed
7;JIRA_8;Bug;User5;Closed

import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(data_frame=df, x=['Request Type'], y=['Status'])
```

So, I want to show in the plot that.

`User1:` 1 ticket with status `Awaiting Review`

`User3:` 4 tickets with status `2: New`, `1: Awaiting Review`, `2: New status`

and so on

Comment: Try with
Replace this line to: 
fig = px.bar(data_frame=df, x='Assignee name', y='Status')
& add 
fig.show()

,you'll get a bar graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you can't do it on the dataframe directly. You need first to count each categories before using plotly, `px.bar` expects a category and its count. The following code produces the plot shown below which does what you requested.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


df = pd.read_csv("data_jira.csv", delimiter=';')
dff = df.groupby(['Assignee name', 'Status'])['N'].count().reset_index(drop=0).rename(columns={'N': 'Count'})

# Change barmode to 'overlay' for stacked barchart
px.bar(data_frame=dff, x='Assignee name', y='Count', color='Status', barmode='group')
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: I am getting KeyError: 'Assignee name'

Comment: I renamed my column to 'Assignee_Name' so just change the column names depending on your dataframe.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to 'Assignee name'. 
df = pd.read_csv( "data_jira.csv") 
dff = df.groupby(['Assignee name', 'Status'])['N'].count(
).reset_index(drop=0).rename(columns={'N': 'Count'}). there is a blank value in one of the 'Assignee Name', so I guess it giving error becauase of dropna=self.dropna,?

Comment: Run this command and check the columns ```print(df.columns)```

Comment: I have modified my question and added a Note in that. Would that help you?

Comment: You should then drop nulls from the ```Assignee name``` column. 
Try this ```df = df[df['Assignee name'].notna()]```

Comment: it's still giving the same error. I don't know why but after read_csv my dataframe looks exactly like how the data looks in my csv file. it's not looking like a dataframe. What could be the issue?

Comment: You should provide a sample of the csv file otherwise there are many possibilities.

Comment: I have provided that in the question above as well